Can I force xdg-open to use a new terminal when opening a terminal app?
I would like xdg-open to open a new terminal when I run it on a file from the terminal and it opens, for example, nvim.
My default text editor for text/plain is set to nvim.desktop. When I open a text/plain file from dolphin, it correctly opens nvim in a new terminal. But when I run xdg-open on that same file from a terminal, it opens nvim in the current terminal instead of starting a new one. How can I force xdg-open to open programs with a Terminal=true flag in their .desktop file in a new terminal when I run xdg-open from a terminal?
I already tried { cat | xdg-open ~/file.txt 2>&1 >>/dev/null ; } & disown (file.txt is present in the home directory) but nothing happens, nvim is not even running if I type pgrep nvim after...
My terminal is konsole, I am using Hyprland as window manager.
Edit:
I found out gio open does this correctly, so for now I will just use that. (I'll consider making it the answer, but I'll just wait a couple of days to see if I get an answer for xdg-open.)

You can try replacing the executable command with konsole -e "nvim %F" (basically, the value after = in the line Exec=... should be replaced with the above
In essence, you will now be executing the nvim command not directly, but rather calling konsole to open a new window and run nvim (with the given filename) in it.

Yea, that would only work for this specific application, I would like it to apply to all applications that use a terminal...
